# In unity, is it possible to have a small animation that doesn't freeze even when a large scene is loading?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity, is it possible to have a small animation that doesn't freeze even when a large scene is loading? Maybe multi threading? I have seen games that doesn't freeze at  all even when they are loading their game, like noita

Comment: In C#, hence in Unity too, anything `Task` based should run in the background without blocking the main UI thread. You can start here - https://www.google.com/search?q=task+vs+thread+-+C%23

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Use `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync` and play the animation. For more information about `LoadAsync` check out the link below.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html

Comment: no, SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync wouldn't work, it will still freeze if the scene is huge and has lots of scripts